# Testing what's written to a Java OutputStream

Tags: java, junit, outputstream

I am about to write junit tests for a XML parsing Java class that outputs directly to an OutputStream. For example `xmlWriter.writeString("foo");` would produce something like `<aTag>foo</aTag>` to be written to the outputstream held inside the XmlWriter instance. The question is how to test this behaviour. One solution would of course be to let the OutputStream be a FileOutputStream and then read the results by opening the written file, but it isn't very elegant.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and then get the data out of that using [toByteArray()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray()). This won't test *how* it writes to the stream (one byte at a time or as a big buffer) but usually you shouldn't care about that anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you can pass a Writer to XmlWriter, I would pass it a `StringWriter`. You can query the `StringWriter`'s contents using `toString()` on it.

If you have to pass an `OutputStream`, you can pass a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and you can also call `toString()` on it to get its contents as a String.

Then you can code something like:

```
public void testSomething()
{
  Writer sw = new StringWriter();
  XmlWriter xw = new XmlWriter(sw);
  ...
  xw.writeString("foo");
  ...
  assertEquals("...<aTag>foo</aTag>...", sw.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simple. As @JonSkeet said:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// pass the baos to be writed with "value", for this example
byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
Assert.assertEquals("value", new String(byteArray));
```